# Creating a Wordpess Plugin that writes data to a csv file. The data doesn't show in the csv file?

Tags: plugin-development, csv

I am writing my first Wordpress Plugin that should simply write data to a csv file. This is the code, I can't figure out why the data won't write to the csv file?

---

```
add_action('admin_menu', 'myfirstplugin_admin_actions');
function myfirstplugin_admin_actions() {
add_options_page('MyFirstPlugin', 'MyFirstPlugin', 'manage_options', __FILE__, 'myfirstplugin_admin');
}

function myfirstplugin_admin()
{

$label = "Entries";

$entries = RGFormsModel::get_form_counts(1);
echo "The Form count for Form #1 is: ".$entries['total'].".";

$cvslabel = array ($label);
$cvsnumber = array ($entries);

$plugin_dir = plugin_dir_path( __FILE__ );
$logfile = $plugin_dir . 'data.csv';

$fp = fopen($logfile, 'w');

fwrite($fp, $cvslabel);
fwrite($fp, $cvsnumber);

fclose($fp);
}
```

---

Can someone explain to me why it won't work? And what i need to do so it will simply write the data to the csv file. I want the data to be dynamic so it will refresh the data in the csv file automatically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your Wordpress code is correct, the problem is the incorrect 2nd param to PHP's [frwite()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fwrite.php), which needs to be a string, and you're passing arrays.

I think you want something like:

```
fwrite ($fp, "$label\n") ;
fwrite ($fp, implode (',', array_keys ($entries)) . "\n") ;
fwrite ($fp, implode (',', array_values ($entries)) . "\n") ;
```

Comment: Also, if you add `define('WP_DEBUG', true);` to your wp-config.php (in you development environment, but not production) then you'll get PHP errors output to the browser, which would have helped you see that the problem was that you're passing arrays to `fwrite()`

Comment: Thank you! It works just like I want indeed. The tip about define('WP_DEBUG', true); helps me a lot  aswell. As you can see I'm pretty new to plugin development so i appreciate the help!